# What is difference between ADOTable and ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, ado

What is the difference between [ADOTable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOTable) and [ClientDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBClient.TClientDataSet)?
Both components are capable of performing Batch Update, why add the extra overhead of having 2 additional components like [ClientDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBClient.TClientDataSet) and [DataSetProvider](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Provider.TDataSetProvider).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that ClientDataSet can operate without a connection to external database. You can use it as in-memory table or load it's contents from file.
In combination with DataSetProvider it is frequently used to overcome limits of unidirectional datasets and as a cache.

Answer (score 3):

A ClientDataSet is an in-memory dataset, which has a lot of usefull additional functionallities.
One big advantage compared to Interbase/Firebird tables and queries is, that you don't need to keep a transaction alive, e.g. as long as you display the data in a grid.

Have a look at this article:
[A ClientDataSet in Every Database Application](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28876)

Answer (score 3):

Client dataset is a generic implementation that works regardless of the underlying db access library. It can work (through the provider) with any TCustomDataset descendant, be it a dbExpress dataset, a BDE one, an ADO one, or any of the many libraries available for Delphi to allow for direct database access using the native client (i.e. ODAC, Direct Oracle Access, ecc. ecc.)

It can also work in a multi-tier mode where the data access dataset and provider are in a remote server application and the TClientDataset is in the client application, allowing for "thin client" deployment which doesn't require database clients or data access library like ADO installed on the client (the required midas.dll code can be linked to the application when using recent versions of Delphi, anyway only the midas.dll is required otherwise).

On top of that it can be used as an in-memory table able to store data in a local file. It allows for the "briefcase" model also, where a thin client can still work when not connected to the database, and then "sync" when a connection becomes available. That's was more useful in the past, when wireless access was not common.

As you can see, TClientDataset offers a lot more of a TADODataset.

Answer (score 0):

The most important difference I can think of is resolving update conflicts. In fact,  TClientDataSet exposes the handy ReconcileErrorForm dialog, which wraps up the process of showing the user the old and new records and allows them to specify what action to take, while with TADOTable for instance, you're basically on your own.